# Combinations - Cards Question

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

Three cards are chosen at random from a pack of 52 cards.
In how many ways this can be done if all the three cards are of different types?

(A) $4 × 13^3$

(B) $13 × 12 × 11$

(C) $\binom {53} {13}$

(D) $(3 × 13) / (12 × 11)$

My approach:

We can select the first card out of 52 cards. Then the next card out of 39 cards and the next one out of 26 cards.

So, $52×39×26/3!$ which is equivalent to option (A). Is this the right approach to solve this question? Am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: I don't understand why this question was downvoted.

Comment: While (c) is clearly wrong, was it supposed to say $\binom{\color{red}{52}}{13}$?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, maybe it's to trick the students. This question was given during my class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is okay, though for the sake of completeness you should also mention why you divided by $3!$.

Another approach is first choosing $3$ out of $4$ types, and after that $1$ card out of each of the chosen types. That gives $\binom43\times13^3$.

Comment: yes! Your approach is more comprehensible. Thanks!